# Converting Age in years to days, hours, minutes, and seconds

Tags: c++

I am having issues with converting age in years to seconds.  It comes up with a wrong number and a negative one.  Can someone please help?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int years;

    years = years;

    cout << "How many years have you lived: " ;

    cin >> years;

    cout << "You have lived: " << years; cout << " years:" << endl;

    int days = 0.5 + (years * 365.25);

    cout << days; cout << " days" << endl;

    int hours = days * 24;

    cout << hours; cout << " hours" << endl;

    int minutes = hours * 60;

    cout << minutes; cout << " minutes" << endl;

    int seconds = minutes * 60;

    cout << seconds; cout << " seconds" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `years = years;` is meaningless and dangerous because indeterminate value in default-initialized variable having automatic storage duration is used. Remove it.

Comment: The problem may be overflow in aritimetic. Try using types with more precision.

Comment: "It comes up with a wrong number and a negative one" is not a useful problem description. "Hello? Mike's Auto Repairs? My car doesn't work, do you have any idea why?"

Comment: example input? expect output? actual output? even running the code may get that, mentioning them in question is more clear,right?

Comment: You do not need to use `cout` all the time like this: `cout << hours; cout << " hours" << endl;` You can combine multiple strings like this: `cout << hours << " hours" << endl;`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting wrong/negative seconds because of overflow problem. **int** can't hold so big numbers (seconds).

So, use **long long minutes** and **long long seconds** instead of **int**

And, don't forget to remove the line

```
years = years;
```

Comment: Or maybe even just `long` if `long long` is unknown.